# URL Decoding issue hotmail

Tags: url

I'm facing issue with the Hotmail URL. When clicking on the below link `"&"` symbol is begin converted into `"%26"` and because of this i'm getting the error. This issue is caused only for the hotmail, the other email clients are working fine with the same url

This is how i have splitted out the code to form the url

```
<Const>/ece/cn=</Const>

<Result>UserEmailDetails/EmailConfirmNumber</Result>

<Const>&amp;em=</Const>

<Result>EmailMessageDetails/EmailTo</Result>
```

Hotmail url

```
ece/cn=0799-4941-1686-7833-8544%26em=cdayanand-us13%40hotmail.com
```

Outlook url

```
/ece/cn=0799-4941-1686-7833-8544&em=cdayanand-us13%40hotmail.com
```